# how to arrange a output of a loop (running on array) in to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, indexing

Sorry if I don't make any sense here, I've only been learning python for a few weeks.

(a) i want to arrange all 4 output arrays in such a way that it comes under one big array and then i can use np.ix_ to place each of the data elements of that list in their respective position.

np.ix_ will give shape mismatch error, as p_r takes only one 4 by 4 array, whereas i wanted them in to a one big array or list.

Thankyou so much !!

sorry, my code is too long, so iam just posting the sample code here.

```
import numpy as np



def transpose():
      
      k = np.zeros((100,100))
      p = np.array([[1,-1],[-1,1]])
      a =np.arange(1,65)
      print(a)
      
      tau = np.array([[ 1, 2,  3,  4],
                     [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])
      
      for i in range(4):
          k[i:i+2,i:i+2] = p
          p_r = tau.T.dot(p).dot(tau)
          print(p_r)
              
          k[np.ix_(a,a)]= p_r
          print(k)
          
          
      return 

print(transpose())
```

Comment: `k` is an array of size (4, 4), while `np.ix_(a, a)` is larger. How is `np.ix_(a, a)` supposed to index `k`?

Comment: yes, it's 4 by 4 but when the loop will run, it will give 4 such arrays (of 4 by 4) 
so , is it possible to make those arrays in to one big list of 64  and then index it ?

Comment: Make `alist=[]` and do `alist.append(k)` instead of the print.